# Prove the inequality for Condition number of matrix

Tags: matrices, condition-number

Let $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a non-singular matrix.

Let $\hat A=A+\delta A, \ \hat x=x+\delta x, \ \text{and} \ \hat b=b+\delta b$ with $Ax=b$ and $\hat A \hat x=\hat b \ $.

Here $||.||$ denote the both vector norm and induced matrix norm.

Show that $ \large  \frac{||\delta x||}{||\large \hat x||} \leq \kappa (A) \left(\frac{||\delta A||}{||A||}+\frac{||\delta b||}{||\hat b||}+\frac{||\delta A|| || \large \delta b||}{||A|||| \large \hat b||} \right)$, where $\kappa(A)=||A||||A^{-1}||. $

**Help me to show it**